# How to manage click on IconToggleButton if I have list of IconToggleButtons in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, list, button, android-jetpack-compose, click

How to manage click on IconToggleButton if I have list of IconToggleButtons?

```
list.forEach { color ->
                IconToggleButton(
                    checked = isChecked,
                    onCheckedChange = { onClick(color.toString()) },
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(
                           
                        ),
                        modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        tint = Color(color)
                    )
                }
            }
```